# unix shell while loop doesn't see the variable

Tags: linux, shell, unix

do you know why in this command, `$x` is visible

```
ls -d */ $1 | while read x; do echo $x; done
```

return the sub directories in the current directory.

However, when I put in another command, `$x` seems to have no value

```
ls -d */ $1 | while read x; do ls -lat /order | grep $x; done
```

return nothing

Comment: Well, the second loop lists the files in `/order` directory, which is not self-evidently related to `*/` or `$1`.  Did you mean to use something else in place of `/order`?

Comment: My intention is to use the result from the ls -d */, say 123, and ls -lat /order | grep 123

Comment: Is there a file `/order/123`?  Or a file in `/order` with `123` in any of the characteristics shown by `ls -lat`?  (length including digits 123, mainly).  If not, the grep won't find anything.

Comment: Oh I see it now. the outcome of ls -d */ contains the / character, so it is 123/. Of course when I grep for 123/ it won't find anything

Comment: Each *pipe* `|` separates commands that are **run in their own separate subshells**. You cannot split a loop across two separate processes.

Comment: What do you want to do? Looking for duplicate files? See what happens with `cd /bin; ls  | while read x; do ls /usr/bin | grep $x; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a / at the end of output before the pipe, you should filter it.

```
ls -d */ $1 | while read xx; do ls -l /order |grep `echo ${xx}|sed  's/.$//'`  ; done
```

Comment: ls -d */ $1 | tr / ' ' | while read x; do ls -l /order | grep $x; done